# Is there any way to force a DNS refresh locally when developing?

Tags: dns

I've been playing around with various DNS setups on Amazon and by far the most annoying part of it all is that I can't tell when the DNS change has propagated to my browser/computer!

`ipconfig /flushdns` doesn't really seem to consistently do anything (I'm on  Windows).

Is there any good way to force a DNS refresh on my development computer so I can test DNS configs more  efficiently?

Using CTRL+SHIFT+R to force a hard refresh on the browser seems to work better but it's still not very consistent.

I have been setting TTL to 60 when testing, but it doesn't seem to be reliable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On chrome you could just flush the dns cache by a click.

```
chrome://net-internals/#dns
```

Go to above url in chrome and click the "clear host cache".